# How can I use my brightness control keys?

Tags: brightness, backlight, ubuntu-minimal

I'm recently trying ubuntu mini.iso with openbox wm and really enjoying it. But I can't control my brightness with special keys on my laptop. Before this I've tried Xubuntu and these keys were working fine. The problem is I can't get `xbacklight` to work though my `/sys/class/backlight` contains a folder `radeon_bl0`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: For that I've to change permission. Moreover I would like to use `xbacklight`. The `-get` and `-set` options would be much easier to handle than reading and writing raw values from `brightness` file.

Comment: As a temporary solution I've installed `xfce4-power-manager` and the brightness control is working fine. People who are having same problem as me , use this fix. But I want a solution for `xbacklight`.